# Is there a way to reuse a generic wildcard across definition of class type?

Tags: java, generics

How can I typesafe something like `Map<S,Map<Class<T>,T>>` for any type ?

If I use that formula, then the map will only hold a concrete S,T types. If I use wildcards, `Map<?,Map<Class<?>,?>>`, the last 2 wildcards will be not enforcedly related.

Any solution?

Comment: it depends on what value you put in S and T. can you post an example of code where you plan to use this?

Comment: You can still have for `S` and `T` this `Map<Object, Map<Class<Object, Object>>` and that will allow anything you put in there, but wont have a strict type for when you want to pull it back out the map

Comment: Might be neater to define an interface `MyGenericMap<S, T> extends Map<S,Map<Class<T>,T>>` (and provide an implementation which wraps a `Map`). Generics like that hurt my eyes and head.

Comment: But then MyGenericMap is expected to hold a concrete but uncertain S and T types at runtime. I really want a wildcard, but then I would not typesafe Map, if only I could do Map<Class<?1>,?1>,

Comment: I'd like to see how you expect to use this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a class for the sole purpose of keeping this relation.

```
public class ClassMap<T> extends HashMap<Class<T>, T> {}
```

Then you can write:

```
Map<?, ClassMap<?>>
```

Comment: Really great and obvious, indeed.... Thanks you very much... too few coffee today :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking for something along the lines of:

```
Cat cat = map.get(Cat.class);
Dog dog = map.get(Dog.class);
```

then no, it is impossible to do in Java.

As a side note, using `Class<T>` means the map would only ever be able to contain one key (the exact class of T). Use `Class<? extends T>` instead.